# Tantalum capacitor at low temperatures

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, tantalum

What could happen to a solid tantalum capacitor that operates below the lower temperature range defined by the manufacturer (-55°C)?

From my understanding, there would be a performance issue with decreased capacitance and increased ESR. However, I don't fully understand if any damage could occur. Generally, high ESR could result in enough heat to cause the MnO<sub>2</sub> to break down and create a defect site.

Ideally, this will self-heal and the defect site will be isolated, but I do not know if the same would take place at excessively cold temperatures. At a molecular level, I'd think heat would still be generated, but I don't know if it would dissipate before a breakdown would occur.

From a material perspective, could the material that surrounds the dielectric cause any damage to the dielectric by contracting and expanding? I'd expect this to cause the capacitor to burn up if this occurs.

Comment: A brainstorm here: Maybe  potential problems would not be caused by the temperature only. A higher power dissipated (↔️ frequency & ripple current on higher ESR), when combined with higher heat transfers (due to thermal gradients & high convection coefficients, as submerged in liquid nitrogen), could maintain thermally induced mechanical stresses.